# PHP: add Comments Count for each Post in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have 2 models "post_model" and "comment_model"

in Post_controller I get a result array from post_model which has all the posts.

I'm trying to add comments count for each post but I couldn't and need help.

- comment table has post_id.

Please let me know how to handle this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you are trying to write query to fetch data right ? Show us query, which you had tried ?

Comment: I have tried this:
select p.post_id,count(c.post_id)
from posts p left join comments c USING(post_id)
group by p.post_id

but it will not work correctly if I used LIMIt 5 for example.
@rahul_m

Comment: It is correct query ! .

Comment: but doesn't work correctly when I use LIMIT

Comment: Ok, check my answer, I modified your query to get required result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT 
  p.post_id,
  (SELECT count(c.post_id) FROM comments c WHERE c.post_id = p.post_id) cnt 
FROM posts p 
GROUP BY p.post_id LIMIT 5
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: awesome :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should give you the number of comments for each post:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS comment_cnt, post_id 
FROM comment_table 
GROUP BY post_id;
```

Then you can traverse the result set and enrich the corresponding post objects.
If you want to count comments only for some specific posts and you know their post_id, you could do something like:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS comment_cnt, post_id 
FROM comment_table 
WHERE post_id IN (post_id1, post_id2, ...) 
GROUP BY post_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.post_title, p.post_content, p.user_id,count(c.post_id)
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN comments c USING(post_id)
GROUP BY p.post_id, p.post_title, p.post_content, p.user_id;
```